# Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas: libappstream-glib8 (>= 0.6.1) - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

en el sistema operativo ubuntu 20.04 intento instalar:

**sudo apt install flatpak**

y como respuesta se me genera que tengo dependencias incumplidas:
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
flatpak : Depende: libappstream-glib8 (>= 0.6.1) pero no es instalable
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos

Intento arreglar las dependencias incumplidas según un tutorial en youtube, pero no aparece ninguna dañada.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Agradezco orientación al respecto. Gracias.